# The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method. Parameter name: name

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, webrequest

Getting error message - The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
i'm getting the response in the post man but not getting in the MVC controller
 i have one basic authentication api with below headers.while using adding accept headers in the request getting the error

```
Content-Type:  application/vnd.onem2m-res+json;ty=4;
Accept: application/vnd.onem2m-res+json;
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-M2M-RI: 9900001
Authorization: Basic QzdBQUNFO
X-M2M-Origin: C7AACE9-25
```

code

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"url");
                req.Method = "GET";
                req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "QzdBQUNFO";
                req.ContentType = "application/vnd.onem2m-res+json";
                req.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.onem2m-res+json;");
                req.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
                req.Headers["X-M2M-RI"] = "9900001";
                req.Headers["X-M2M-Origin"] = "C7AACE9-25";
                HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                var encoding = resp.CharacterSet == "" ? Encoding.UTF8 : Encoding.GetEncoding(resp.CharacterSet);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"url");
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "QzdBQUNFO";
            req.ContentType = "application/vnd.onem2m-res+json";
            req.Accept = "application/vnd.onem2m-res+json";
            req.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
            req.Headers["X-M2M-RI"] = "9900001";
            req.Headers["X-M2M-Origin"] = "C7AACE9-25";
            HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            var encoding = resp.CharacterSet == "" ? Encoding.UTF8 : Encoding.GetEncoding(resp.CharacterSet);
```

[microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.accept?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in that line: `req.Accept "application/vnd.onem2m-res+json;";`

Comment: Hi I am stuck with the same problem, have you got the clue, I meant how can perform in nodejs or php or python...

Answer (score 7):

You must change the header name in some case below:

```
//req.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.onem2m-res+json;");
req.Headers.Add("20", "application/vnd.onem2m-res+json;");
```

Following are the allowed list of web header below:

```
CacheControl = 0
Date = 2
Connection = 1
Date = 2
KeepAlive = 3
Pragma = 4,
Trailer = 5
TransferEncoding = 6
 Upgrade = 7
Via = 8
Warning = 9
Allow = 10
ContentLength = 11
ContentType = 12
ContentEncoding = 13
ContentLanguage = 14
ContentLocation = 15
ContentMd5 = 16
 ContentRange = 17
Expires = 18
LastModified = 19
Accept = 20
AcceptCharset = 21
AcceptEncoding = 22
AcceptLanguage = 23
Authorization = 24
Cookie = 25
Expect = 26
From = 27
Host = 28
IfMatch = 29
 IfModifiedSince = 30
IfNoneMatch = 31
 IfRange = 32
IfUnmodifiedSince = 33
MaxForwards = 34
ProxyAuthorization = 35
Referer = 36
 Range = 37
Te = 38
Translate = 39
UserAgent = 40
```

Hope it can help you!

Comment: This works for me. I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.1. There is no "Accept" method for the WebRequest class. Does anyone know what happened with this method?

Comment: Could you add an explanation for this? At the first glance it looks like a complete magic and my spontaneous reaction is just "wft?!"

Comment: The list that you see is the HttpRequestHeader enum

Comment: Documentation says "On .NET Framework, some common headers are considered restricted and are either exposed directly by the API (such as Content-Type) or protected by the system and cannot be changed." It seems like the original terms work with .NET Core, though.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using a System.Net.WebRequest object, use a System.Net.HttpWebRequest object.

The WebRequest object does not support the Accept property, but the HttpWebRequest object does. Example code:

```
// Create a 'HttpWebRequest' object which support Accept property
HttpWebRequest req=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"url");
                req.Method = "GET";
                req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "QzdBQUNFO";
                req.ContentType = "application/vnd.onem2m-res+json";
                req.Accept = "application/vnd.onem2m-res+json;";
                req.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
                req.Headers["X-M2M-RI"] = "9900001";
                req.Headers["X-M2M-Origin"] = "C7AACE9-25";
```

Microsoft docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.accept?view=netframework-4.6

Comment: Documentation says not to use the HttpWebRequest: "We don't recommend that you use HttpWebRequest for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class." It goes on to say that the WebRequest.Create will create the HttpWebRequest as necessary.

Comment: @phrebh Okay... I will have to go back and review that. Thanks.